# Powershell for creating folders and subfolders from csv

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-3.0

I try to prepare a script that will create folders and subfolders from CSV.

When I create a CSV with 1 column 'Name' like so

```
Name
XYZ
ZXX
FFF
```

with the following script I can achieve creation of folders

```
$folder = "D:\Test\"
$name = Import-Csv D:\Test\Test.csv
Foreach ($line in $name)
{
    New-Item -path $folder -Name $line.Name -Type Directory
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to have CSV like this

```
Name;Letter 
XYZ;A
ZXX;B
FFF;B
```

I want that the script creates folder $Folder\Letter\Name (so the final path is D:Test\A\XYZ; D:Test\B\ZXX; D:Test\B\FFF). Any advice is welcomed.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the desired result

```
Import-Csv 'D:\Test\Test.csv' -Delimiter ';' |
    % { 
        $path = Join-Path $folder $_.Letter; 
        New-Item -Path $path -Name $_.Name -Type Directory 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to improve the script little bit. In CSV files is the name and letter that works fine with the script what was provided by DAXaholic, but would need to add some more subfolders into the folder Name. I tried this, but it doesn't work as I need.

```
    $folder = "D:\Test\"
    $subfolders = "Volvo","Skoda","Tesla"
    $file = Import-Csv 'D:\Test\Test.csv' -Delimiter ';' 
    $file | 
     % { 
            $path = Join-Path $folder $_.Letter; 
            New-Item -Path $path -Name $_.Name -Type Directory 
    }

foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders) 
{
$file | 
%{
 $path2 = Join-Path $folder $_.Letter $_.Name;
 New-Item -Path $path2\$subfolder -Type Directory 
}
    }
```

What I would like to achieve is following. Script should check the CSV file, create the user in CSV file put it in the folder and create 3 subfolders in the name folder. E.g D:\Test\A\XYZ\Volvo,Skoda,Tesla. What am I missing in the script? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if somebody would need similar script, then here is the solution

```
$folder = "D:\Test\"
$subfolders = "Volvo","Skoda","Tesla"
$file = Import-Csv 'D:\Test\Test.csv' -Delimiter ';' 
$file | 
 % { 
        $path = Join-Path $folder $_.Letter; 
        New-Item -Path $path -Name $_.Name -Type Directory 
}
foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders)
{ 
$file | %{
 $path2 = Join-Path $folder $_.Letter;
 $path3 = Join-Path $path2 $_.Name;
 New-Item -Path $path3\$subfolder -Type Directory 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was put the desired path in my CSV file.
Silmiar to the above discussion.
"FilePath" can be replaced with any filepath that you have access to read/write from/to.
"Folders.csv" is the name of the CSV File that I used. You can name that csv file whatever you want as long as powershell can access it. And that it is something that the computer does not have a problem with the name of the file. Most computers will tell you if it does not like the csv filename that you use. If not PowerShell will tell you.

Here is an example of my PowerShell Code:

```
$path = "FilePath"
$Name = import-csv -Path 'FilePath\Folders.csv'
foreach ($i in $Name) {
New-Item -Path $path -Name $i.Name -ItemType Directory
}
```

Sample CSV File has this:

`Name;Testing\A\A.1;Testing\B\B.1;Testing\C\C.1;Testing\D\D.1`

Note: In the CSV file it would look more like this:

```
Name
Testing\A\A.1
Testing\B\B.1
Testing\C\C.1
Testing\D\D.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the following PowerShell script that will create folders and different subfolders underneath those folders based on a CSV file.

```
#Set Location for folder creation

Set-Location "S:\Folder" 

# Import the CSV file
$csvFile = Import-Csv "S:\Folder\FolderNames1.csv"

# Loop through each row in the CSV file
foreach ($row in $csvFile) {

    # Get the folder path
    $Folder = $row.Folder

    # Create the folder
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Folder

    # If the row contains subfolder names, create each subfolder
    if ($row.Subfolder) {
        foreach ($Subfolder in $row.Subfolder) {
            $subFolderPath = $folder + "\" + $Subfolder
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $SubfolderPath
        }
    }
}
```

The CSV had the following format

```
Folder,Subfolder
Folder 1,Subfolder1
Folder 1,Subfolder2
Folder 1,Subfolder3
Folder 2,Subfolder4
Folder 2,Subfolder5
Folder 2,Subfolder6
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is reasonable code:

```
Set-Location "D:\Folder" 
$subfolders = "1.Requested","2.Evidence","3.Complete"
$Folders = Import-Csv D:\Folder\csv\Fodlers.csv 
 
ForEach ($Folder in $Folders) { 
 
New-Item $Folder.Name -type directory 
  Foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders)
   { 
 $path = Join-Path $Folder.Name -ChildPath " ";
 New-Item $path\$subfolder -Type Directory 
   }
}
```

Copyright: Nguyen Ngo Anh Tuan